# GridSearchCV is Giving me ValueError: number of labels does not match number of samples

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a grid CV parameter search using sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV. I keep getting a ValueError that is really confusing me.
Below I've included the code for the pipeline I created, which includes a TfidfVectorizer and a RandomForestClassifier. I used train_test_split to separate the features and target, and tried to fit the grid search with the pipeline. Here are my results.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

features = ['id', 'description']
target = 'ratingCategory'
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
    train[features],
    train[target],
    test_size=0.2,
    stratify=train[target],
    random_state=95
)

vect = TfidfVectorizer()
clf = RandomForestClassifier()

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('vect', vect), 
    ('clf', clf)]
)

parameters = {
    'vect__min_df': (0.01, 0.05),
    'clf__ccp_alpha': (0.1, 0.5)
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameters, cv=5, n_jobs=4, verbose=1)
grid_search.fit(X=x_train, y=y_train)
```

Checking the shape of the matrices confirms that x_train and y_train have the same length (the number of rows in both = 3269).
So I'm confused as to why fitting the grid search gives me the following error:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 4 candidates, totalling 20 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 4 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done  20 out of  20 | elapsed:    2.0s finished
--------------------
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-4e85850d6599> in <module>
      29 grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameters, cv=5, n_jobs=4, verbose=1)
----> 30 grid_search.fit(X=x_train, y=y_train)

........................................

ValueError: Number of labels=3269 does not match number of samples=2
```

What does it mean by number of labels and samples? There *should* be 3269 samples, since the shape of both X and y matrices is (3269, 2) and (3269, ), respectively.

Any help is super appreciated! Let me know if the full traceback would help, but it was extremely long so I didn't include it.

Comment: First thing to note, you are passing 2 columns: id and description to TfidfVectorizer, when you should pass only a text column (description)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# features = ['description']
# target = 'ratingCategory'
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
    # train[features],
    train.description,
    # train[target],
    train.ratingCategory,
    test_size=0.2,
    # stratify=train[target],
    stratify=train.ratingCategory,
    random_state=95
)

vect = TfidfVectorizer()
clf = RandomForestClassifier()

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('vect', vect), 
    ('clf', clf)]
)

parameters = {
    'vect__min_df': (0.01, 0.05),
    'clf__ccp_alpha': (0.1, 0.5)
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameters, cv=5, n_jobs=4, verbose=1)
grid_search.fit(X=x_train, y=y_train)
```

Comment: I thought it might be that too, but when I make the change the error is the same, only this time it says: ValueError: Number of labels=3269 does not match number of samples=1

Comment: Please try with the edit I made

Comment: Great! I've been going crazy, thank you! Could you explain to me why this method worked?

Comment: Sure, I had the same issue long ago and I realize that TFIDFVectorizer expects a pd.Series not a DataFrame, when you select the "description" features as train[["description"]] this is a DataFrame whereas with train.description is a series (what the vectorizer expects)